# Need to port FreeBSD to the MIPS® platform

Tags: freebsd, mips32

Need to port FreeBSD to the MIPS® platform. I was going through below url, 
https://www.freebsd.org/platforms/mips.html
There is list  of all supported  CPUs,boards but list is long, I would like to know the CPUs and boards on which anybody tried it and successfully able to execute it. Please suggest the name of cpu and board on which it works.
Thanks,
Umesh

Answer (score 0):

There is also a wiki page: https://wiki.freebsd.org/FreeBSD/mips with a list.

If you have a further question, i suggest to ask on the freebsd-mips Mailinglist.